# How to pass value from controller to input HTML in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How do I pass a value from my controller to `<input>`tag in my view? I got the data successfully but calling it from the html, it's not working? I don't get any errors, my syntax is just wrong, I tried several syntax base from angularjs documentation, I also tried using `ng-value={{data.email}}` and even placing double quotes between the value. What is the proper way to do this?

this is my html:

```
<label class="item item-input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" value={{data.email}} disabled>
</label>
```

this is my controller:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'myservice',
    data: encodedString,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).success(function (data) {
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].QActivationCode === data[i].token) {
            $scope.userData = data[i];
            Acct.setAcctEmail(data[i].email);
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Your HTML references `data`, but you actually assign the data to `$scope.userData`

Comment: damn, i didn't knew about that, because I tried doing this in my previous app, it's working but now it didn't work when I pass the value to the input.. many thanks Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either `ng-model` or `ng-value`. You are using the wrong key in the view i.e. you should use `userData.email` instead of `data.email` in the HTML view. (The statement `$scope.userData = data[i];` states that you are adding the key `userData` in the scope not the `data`):

### Using ng-model

```
<label class="item item-input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" ng-model="userData.email" disabled>
</label>
```

### Using value

```
 <label class="item item-input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" value={{userData.email}} disabled>
</label>
```

Since the `input` field is disabled and we do not need to alter that input field so you should use the 2nd option.

Answer (score 1):

In angular, ng-model is used to bind the scope values with the html elements. Or we can use {{}} expression if we have to pass the value to the input tags.

### Small description about ng-model:

The ngModel directive binds an input , select , textarea (or custom form control) to a property on the scope using NgModelController, which is created and exposed by this directive. ngModel is responsible for: Binding the view into the model, which other directives such as input , textarea or select require.

### Corrected html code is attached below:

```
1. <label class="item item-input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" ng-model="userData.email" disabled>
</label>

2. <label class="item item-input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" value={{userData.email}} disabled>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

use ng-model

```
<label class="item item-input">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Email" ng-value="data.email" disabled>
</label>
```

make sure that object data exist on the scope.

Comment: i already did this, for some reason this didn't work, i don't know why.. but the comment on the answer already gave me the correct output.. but thanks for the reply sir @mtamma